# Get value on dropdown change with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this dropdown:

```
<div class="m-b-lg" id="change_booking_status">
    <div class="btn-group btn-block">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block dropdown-toggle text-left" data-toggle="dropdown">Status <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a data-value="Confirmed"> Confirmed </a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a data-value="NotConfirmed"> NotConfirmed </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

On each change on this dropdown, I need to get the value in the `data-value` except for the `class="divider"`.

So I stated like this:

```
$('#change_booking_status').on('click', 'div > ul > li', function() {
    alert($(this).data('value'));
});
```

But I doesn't work.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the selector from:

```
'div > ul > li'
```

to:

```
'div > ul > li a'
```

all work fine.

Instead, if you cannot change you must find the element anchor and get the corresponding data value :

```js
$('#change_booking_status').on('click', 'div > ul > li', function() {
  console.log('First way: ' + $(this).find('a').data('value'));
});

$('#change_booking_status').on('click', 'div > ul > li a', function() {
  console.log('Second way: ' + $(this).data('value'));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="m-b-lg" id="change_booking_status">
    <div class="btn-group btn-block">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block dropdown-toggle text-left" data-toggle="dropdown">Status <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a data-value="Confirmed"> Confirmed </a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a data-value="NotConfirmed"> NotConfirmed </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```